# Pine script - If ATR value equals

Tags: pine-script, trading, back-testing, pine-script-v5

how can I check value of ATR with "if"? Let's say atr now eqauls 0.86.

I need to check that (code below), but "if statement" does not work. Strategy Tester shows No Data.

```
atr = ta.atr(14)

if (atr == 0.86)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do an exact match and it might be hard to get it on exact 0.86 atr value with 2 decimal places only.

Instead either try greater than or equal to OR less than equal to depending on your requirement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
atr = ta.atr(14)
atr2 = (atr * 100)
atr3 = math.round(atr2)

if (atr3 == 86)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
```